# Within the same function, is it UB to access—through indirection—a local variable not in scope?

Tags: c, scope, undefined-behavior

After the second closing brace, `b` is accessible only through indirection through `a`.

```
int main() {
    int *a;
    {
        int b = 42;
        a = &b;
    }
    printf("%d", *a); // UB?
    return 0;
}
```

Since `b` is not anymore in scope, is this UB? I know it's UB to dereference a pointer to a non-static local variable from a function that has already returned, but in this case everything is within the same function.

This is UB in C++, but I'm not sure about C.

Comment: If you were to declare `int c = 255;` just before the printf I predict you will get a 255 instead of a 42. This should show that the stack area for `int b` got discarded and reused.

Comment: @ZanLynx with clang 3.2 it still prints 42 both with and without optimizations enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's undefined behaviour to access *any* variable that has reached it's **end of life.** Scope and storage duration are subtly different here. Scope is more "when is the variable identifier visible?" and storage duration is "when does the variable itself exist?".

You can have things in scope and enduring such as:

```
int main (void) {
    int spoon = 42;
    // spoon is both in scope and enduring here
    return 0;
}
```

Or out of scope but enduring:

```
int main (void) {
    int *pSpoon;
    {
        static int spoon = 42;
        pSpoon = &spoon;
    }
    // spoon is out of scope but enduring here (use *pSpoon to get to it)
    return 0;
}
```

You can also have variables out of scope and not enduring, such as with:

```
int main (void) {
    // spoon is neither in scope nor enduring here ("there is no spoon")
    return 0;
}
```

In fact, the only thing you can't have is a variable in scope but not enduring. The identifier is tied to the the storage since it makes little sense allowing a variable with no backing storage.

I'm not talking about pointers here, that's an extra level of indirection - an in-scope pointer variable *always* has storage for the pointer value itself, even if the thing it points *to* has ended, or not yet begun, its storage duration.

The fact that undefined behaviour may work in some situations in no way makes the behaviour defined, in fact that's one of the most annoying features of undefined behaviour in that it sometimes *does* work. Otherwise it would be much easier to detect.

In this particular case, the `b` variable storage duration ends at the inner closing brace so trying to access it after that point is not wise.

---

The controlling part of the standard is `c11 6.2.4 Storage duration of objects` (slightly paraphrased to remove unnecessary bits):

> An object has a storage duration that determines its lifetime. There are four storage
>   durations: static, thread, automatic, and allocated.
>
> An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the storage-class specifier static has automatic storage duration.
>
> For such an object, its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way.

Comment: The behavior is defined as undefined.

Comment: @Stacked: No, the behaviour is _declared_ as undefined :-) C coders should understand the declaration/definition distinction.

Comment: The part of section 6.2.1 that you quoted only mentions scope of identifiers, not the objects they may represent.

Comment: Since the argument to `printf` is `*a`, I think 6.2.4 (2) "The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime." is more pertinent. (Plus 6.5.3.2 (4), Fn 102: "... Among the invalid values ...  and the address of an object after the end of its lifetime.")

Comment: @DanielFischer the lifetime of `b` is until the closing brace, right?

Answer (score 5):

`b` is still within a different, nested, scope that has exited and thus destroyed `b` by the time you access it. So it IS **undefined behavior**. Everything being within the same function is immaterial.

For the purposes of variable lifetimes, you can think of "functions that have returned" as nested scopes, or vice versa.

Comment: Just one nitpick (which was in my original answer as well). Its scope has ended but that's not the problem here. That simply means you can't use `b` to get to it since `b` is not visible. The problem is that the _storage duration_ has also ended which means that you can't use _anything_ (such as `*a`) to get to it either.

Comment: @paxdiablo, those might be two seperate concepts(life of the variable and life of the object refered to by the variable) but in a language like C++ which supports only Value types natively, I would say they are very closely intertwined, as long as the variables are defined on the stack and not pointers to heap allocated objects

Comment: @KarthikT the question is about C, not C++.

Comment: @Zoidberg'-- Ah yes, and now its too late to edit now.. anyway the point works for C just as well.