# Detecting access to out-of-scope variables

Tags: c++, c, valgrind, undefined-behavior

[Code like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14116370/25507) is undefined behavior, because it accesses a local variable that's no longer in scope (whose lifetime has ended).

```
int main() {
    int *a;
    {
        int b = 42;
        a = &b;
    }
    printf("%d", *a); // UB!
    return 0;
}
```

My question: Are there good techniques for automatically detecting bugs like this?  It seems like it ought to be detectable (mark portions of stack space as unusable when variables go out of scope, then complain if that space is accessed), but Valgrind 3.10, Clang 4's AddressSanitizer and UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer, and GCC 6's AddressSanitizer and UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer all don't complain.

Comment: I'd bet that Purify does, but I don't know how much that goes for any more now that Valgrind and other lesser-but-free tools have proliferated.

Comment: C and C++ aren't the same language. They're very different these days.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux *Questions asking for tools are explicitly off topic on Stack Overflow*  But a simple rephrase to "**How** can I detect access of out-of-scope variables" probably passes.  I don't think the questioner is a noob...

Comment: @tambre - Understood, although this particular undefined behavior issue affects them both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without special compiler support, non-intrusive memory debuggers such as Valgrind can detect access to stack frames that have gone out of scope, but not to scopes within functions. This is because compilers (typically) [allocate all the memory for a stack frame in a single pass](http://valgrind.10908.n7.nabble.com/dangling-pointers-out-of-scope-C-not-detected-td49365.html)*. Therefore to detect access to out of scope variables within the same function, we need specific compiler instrumentation to "poison" variables that have gone out of scope but whose enclosing frame is still valid.

The technique used by the ubsan [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer), available in recent versions of clang and gcc, is to [replace stack access with access to specially allocated memory](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerUseAfterReturn#algorithm):

> In order to implemented quarantine for the stack memory we need to promote stack to heap.
>   [...]
>   `__asan_stack_malloc(real_stack, frame_size)` allocates a fake frame (frame_size bytes) from a thread-local heap-like structure (fake stack). Every fake frame comes unpoisoned and then the redzones are poisoned in the instrumented function code. `__asan_stack_free(fake_stack, real_stack, frame_size)` poisons the entire fake frame and deallocates it.

Example of usage and output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp -fsanitize=address && env ASAN_OPTIONS='detect_stack_use_after_return=1' ./a.out 
ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7fd0e8300020 at pc 0x000000400c1b bp 0x7fff5b45ecf0 sp 0x7fff5b45ece8
READ of size 4 at 0x7fd0e8300020 thread T0
    #0 0x400c1a in main (a.out+0x400c1a)
    #1 0x7fd0ebe18d5c in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x1ed5c)
    #2 0x400a48  (a.out+0x400a48)

Address 0x7fd0e8300020 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 32 in frame
    #0 0x400b26 in main (a.out+0x400b26)

  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 36) 'b' <== Memory access at offset 32 is inside this variable
```

Note that because it is expensive it must be requested both at compile time (`-fsanitize=address`) and at run time (`ASAN_OPTIONS='detect_stack_use_after_return=1'`). Regarding minimum versions; it works with gcc 7.1.0 and clang trunk, but apparently not any released versions of clang, so if you want to use a released compiler you'll have to use gcc.

---

* Consider that these two functions compile (e.g. by gcc at `-O0`) to identical machine code, so there is no way** for a non-intrusive memory debugger to tell the difference between them:

```
int f() {
    int* a;
    {
        int b = 42;
        a = &b;
    }
    return *a;
}

int g() {
    int* a;
    int b = 42;
    a = &b;
    return *a;
}
```

** Strictly speaking, if debug symbols are available a debugger could track variables going in and out of scope. But generally if you have debug symbols available you have the source code, so can recompile the program with instrumentation.

Comment: `VALGRIND_MAKE_MEM_NOACCESS` can be used to explicitly mark memory invalid in `valgrind` with tool `memcheck`. Of course, an automated solution is in general much better.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you. I did some further testing, and it looks like both GCC 7.1 and development builds of Clang 5.x can detect stack use after a local scope (but not necessarily stack use after leaving the function) without setting `detect_stack_use_after_return=1`. This includes official development builds of Clang 5.x from http://apt.llvm.org/, so I at least don't have to check out and build it myself.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Lint is designed for this. We use it a lot in embedded systems and automotive systems. [You can use the online demo to test out how well it would work for you.](http://www.gimpel-online.com/OnlineTesting.html) In your specific case, its rule `MISRA:2012:18.6.`

## Sample Run

---

```
FlexeLint for C/C++ (Unix) Vers. 9.00L, Copyright Gimpel Software 1985-2014
--- Module: misra3.c (C)
        _
     1  int main() {
misra3.c  1  Note 970:  Use of modifier or type 'int' outside of a typedef [MISRA 2012 Directive 4.6, advisory]
misra3.c  1  Note 9075:  external symbol 'main(void)' defined without a prior declaration [MISRA 2012 Rule 8.4, required]
            _
     2      int *a;
misra3.c  2  Note 970:  Use of modifier or type 'int' outside of a typedef [MISRA 2012 Directive 4.6, advisory]
     3      {
                _
     4          int b = 42;
misra3.c  4  Note 970:  Use of modifier or type 'int' outside of a typedef [MISRA 2012 Directive 4.6, advisory]
                      _
     5          a = &b;
misra3.c  5  Info 733:  Assigning address of auto variable 'b' to outer scope symbol 'a' [MISRA 2012 Rule 18.6, required]
     6      }
            _
     7      printf("%d", *a); // UB!
misra3.c  7  Info 718:  Symbol 'printf' undeclared, assumed to return int [MISRA 2012 Rule 17.3, mandatory]
misra3.c  7  Warning 586:  function 'printf' is deprecated. [MISRA 2012 Rule 21.6, required]
misra3.c  7  Info 746:  call to function 'printf()' not made in the presence of a prototype
     8      return 0;
                    _
     9  }

misra3.c  9  Info 783:  Line does not end with new-line
misra3.c  9  Note 954:  Pointer variable 'a' (line 2) could be declared as pointing to const [MISRA 2012 Rule 8.13, advisory]

/// Start of Pass 2 ///

--- Module: misra3.c (C)
     1  int main() {
     2      int *a;
     3      {
     4          int b = 42;
     5          a = &b;
     6      }
     7      printf("%d", *a); // UB!
     8      return 0;
     9  }

--- Global Wrap-up

Warning 526:  Symbol 'printf()' (line 7, file misra3.c) not defined
Warning 628:  no argument information provided for function 'printf()' (line 7, file misra3.c)
```

Comment: It produces so much garbage so value of that hint is questionable

Comment: @Slava Typically we have "known safe-to-use" overrides that disable certain rules, keeping the SNR viable. Also, if we want anything going into production, mission critical RTOS systems, we typically have insurance/legal requirements for the code to adhere to a standard such as MISRA.

Comment: Thanks God I do not have this bureaucratic nonsense on top of what we already have

Comment: *"function 'printf' is deprecated."* Seriously?

Comment: Linters will find all suspicious code at first, it takes a while to fine tune the linter to only report on the errors that you consider to be important.

Comment: I hope that most of the "undeclared" infoes will disappear if header files were included.

Comment: @dbush: All variadic functions are deprecated in MISRA, as is `stdio.h`. If you still want to use them, you're supposed to make a deviation (i.e. justify your decision and explain what steps you are taking to avoid problems), and keep that in your project documentation. MISRA is mostly designed for mission critical embedded systems and not intended for "mainstream" application development.

Comment: @Slava Following up on ArneVogel's point, it's restricted to mission critical stuff, and I'm glad we use(d) it. If someone so much as suggested STL, templates, or Boost, all the people in the room would look at them with genuine curiosity as to whether or not they belonged on the project. It wasn't a bureaucratic requirement that was just dumped on us, but rather a technical/QoS one required for certain types of business/liability insurance to be valid, various FIPS/ISO/etc certs, etc.